# Porting a Google Maps app to Osmdroid - problem with overlay

Tags: android

I'm porting a Google Maps based project to Osmdroid in order to use OpenStreetMaps. The port is working OK apart from adding my overlay which consists of a number of straight lines and some text. In both projects I add the Overlay by means of a timer thread and handler calling redrawOverlay.

In the OSM project my overlay is just a grey square completely hiding the map. If I remove the call to redrawOveraly, the OSM tiles are shown OK. I've reduced the overlay code to the bare minimum of a single diagonal line in the code samples below. It works fine in the Google app, overlaying the map tile. The com.google.android.maps.Overlay has a draw method, the OSM has an onDraw, so I have in the OSM version:

```
   private MapView mv;
   private MapOverlay mmapOverlay = null;

   private void redrawOverlay() {

   gPt = mv.getMapCenter();
   if (mmapOverlay == null)
      mmapOverlay = new MapOverlay(getApplicationContext());
      List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mv.getOverlays();
      listOfOverlays.clear();
      listOfOverlays.add(mmapOverlay);
      mv.invalidate();
   }

   public class MapOverlay extends org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay {

   public MapOverlay(Context ctx) {
      super(ctx);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

      @Override
      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView) {

      Paint lp3;
      lp3 = new Paint();
      lp3.setColor(Color.RED);
      lp3.setAntiAlias(true);
      lp3.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      lp3.setStrokeWidth(1);
      lp3.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
      lp3.setTextSize(12);
      canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 150, 150, lp3);
   }
```

Whilst in the Google maps original I have the equivalent :

```
  public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {


   @Override
   public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
   long when) {
      super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
      Paint lp3;
      lp3 = new Paint();
      .....etc.
```

redrawOverlay is the same except the instantiation of the overlay is just:

```
mmapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
```

All suggestions will be gratefully received

**UPDATE Question for kurtzmarc:**

Thanks for you help so far, I see that you are one of the authors of Osmdroid. I like what it's doing so far. I would like to suppress the 'jump to and zoom in' that you get on double tap. I'd like it to do nothing at all. I think it's probably hitting this bit in your source and doing the zoomInFixing:

```
private class MapViewDoubleClickListener implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onDoubleTap(final MotionEvent e) {
   for (int i = mOverlays.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      if (mOverlays.get(i).onDoubleTapUp(e, MapView.this))
         return true;

      final GeoPoint center = getProjection().fromPixels(e.getX(), e.getY());
      return zoomInFixing(center);
  }
```

It doesn't seem that I can override it. I'm using the 3.0.1 jar and the associated javadocs. I'm wondering if the Mapview's setTouchDelegate method would help, but there is no reference to it in the javadocs. Have you any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are calling redrawOverlay() from, but if you look at the MinimapOverlay you will see an example where something is drawn at a fixed location on the screen. In other words, you are drawing in screen coordinates not in map coordinates.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas pC, final MapView pOsmv) {
  // Calculate the half-world size
  final Rect viewportRect = new Rect();
  final Projection projection = pOsmv.getProjection();
  final int zoomLevel = projection.getZoomLevel();
  final int tileZoom = projection.getTileMapZoom();
  mWorldSize_2 = 1 << (zoomLevel + tileZoom - 1);

  // Find what's on the screen
  final BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox = projection.getBoundingBox();
  final Point upperLeft = org.osmdroid.views.util.Mercator
            .projectGeoPoint(boundingBox.getLatNorthE6(), boundingBox.getLonWestE6(),
            zoomLevel + tileZoom, null);
  final Point lowerRight = org.osmdroid.views.util.Mercator
     .projectGeoPoint(boundingBox.getLatSouthE6(), boundingBox.getLonEastE6(), zoomLevel
     + tileZoom, null);

  // Save the Mercator coordinates of what is on the screen
  viewportRect.set(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, lowerRight.x, lowerRight.y);

  // Offset into OSM coordinates
  viewportRect.offset(-mWorldSize_2, -mWorldSize_2);

  // Draw a line from one corner to the other
  canvas.drawLine(viewportRect.left, viewportRect.top, viewportRect.right, viewportRect.bottom);
```

From here viewportRect represents the upper left to the lower right of the screen. You can use this to draw at any fixed points on the screen.

**UPDATE:**

To answer your second question - what you need to do is override onDoubleTap in your Overlay and return "true". Returning "true" indicates to the base class that you "consumed" the event and no further processing should take place. Take a look at the minimap overlay code for a good example:

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/MinimapOverlay.java

We are right in the middle of overhauling the Overlays, so some of this will be handled a little better in the near future. For example, the getOverlays().clear() bug you ran into has also been reported elsewhere and we've since fixed it.

Comment: That certainly draws a line on the screen OK, once I defined mWorldSize_2 as int and added a Paint argument to the .drawline. (I guess the Canvas that gets passed in is completely different to the one that Google Maps passes). However the underlying MapView disappears, I just get a line over a a grey background.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm getting there slowly! The listOfOverlays.clear() was the culprit; I needed to clear them all except for the one at index 0. (It's not the same as for Google maps). My main problem now is that I'd done a lot of work to get the coordinates of the lines and some text that I want drawn via a service/remote interface I wrote. These are in screen pixel coordinates because that's how the Google overlays wanted them. I need now to transform them all into OSM coordinates for Osmdroid.

Comment: Done it! Thanks very much. After I'd cleared my head and sat down with a pen and paper, I realised I just needed to write a couple of two line transformX, transformY routines. It looks just like the Google maps overlays now.

Comment: I've edited the original question to include another query. Hope you don't mind. I don't think any other members of SO will be able to help as I can see that you are still writing the code for Osmdroid

Comment: Fwiw, the link is broken.  Lots of samples [here](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FOpenStreetMapViewer%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fosmdroid%2Fsamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed).  I'd assume `MinimapOverlay.java`'s analog is now `SampleWithMinimapItemizedoverlay.java`, but I haven't played around yet.