# OSMDroid simple example required

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that uses offline maps and custom tiles.
For this I have decided to use OSMDroid and have included the jar within my project.
I will create my custom tiles using MOBAC.

I have been directed to these examples: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FOpenStreetMapViewer%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fosmdroid%2Fsamples

but I am struggling to follow them as I am new to both java and android.

I have created a class file called test (which I have created following an example!):

```
public class test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

 protected static final String PROVIDER_NAME = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);

    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    map.getController().setZoom(16);
    map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(30266000, -97739000));

}
```

}

with a layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tilesource="MapquestOSM" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this I see no map, just an empty grid.
I think this is due to my tilesource but I'm not sure what I need to change it to.

UPDATE:
I also have the following in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can anyone help?

Bex

**Solution**
Make sure the position of the permissions is in the correct place in the manifest!

Comment: can i ask something @Bex,.... is this you get the map offline i mean, trully without the android being connected to the internet?

Comment: @gumuruh This is a very old post, but yes, the map was truly offline (once it had been intially downloaded). I suspect there is a new way of doing things now though.

Comment: i see then, thanks alot @Bex, ... but unfortunately the newest way is using another SDK which is called nutiteq but i ended up without success for the offline part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
```

as did:

```
setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

I didn't need to have anything in the the XML

It's coming back to be now, I had to add one of these:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

to the manifest.xml.

I can't remember which one was necessary but if you put all 3 in, it should work.

Well here's my entire source, which I've just run on the emulator:

```
package com.nbt.osmdroidtest;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OsmDroidTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134733);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);
    }
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Give it a minute or so to load, as initially it might be quite slow in building up a cache.
Those coordinates should put you over central London. If you still have problems see if there is anything illuminating in the logcat.

And the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"

/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @NickT thanx for the reply! I have tried both these but with the same result! I am definitely missing something.Any ideas?

Comment: @NickT.. that's one thing the documentation was very clear about adding to the manifest. http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUseJar so again not the problem! :(

Comment: Do you know does my class have to extend anything other than activity?

Comment: Mine doesn't, posted my entire code which worked once I added those lines to the manifest. Before I did the logcat was full of security exceptions

Comment: What's in your layout file just so I can make sure that is the same?

Comment: Posted my main.xml. I tried your coordinates, they work fine - sent me to Austin, Texas

Comment: Ahhh works! And the reason was not the code.. but the position of my permissions in the manifest! Told you I was new..! Your suggestion of looking in the log cat told me that! I keep forgetting about that..! Thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome. If you have more problems with say, overlays and the like, I got a great deal of help from the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910410/porting-a-google-maps-app-to-osmdroid-problem-with-overlay

Comment: Great answer, in my case the code was similar to yours so I decided to look for other reasons - turns out my VD did not have an SD card configured. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: hey, hey,... sorry for bumping in about this osmdroid. But where do you guys got the map come from? @StevenKramer

Comment: Cool! this is taken from this doc https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library thank

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the crash bubbly had, you need to add osmdroid-android.jar and slf4j-android.jar to libs in your project. See [Simple osmdroid application doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956644/simple-osmdroid-application-doesnt-work-resolved?rq=1) for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
    final MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//显示缩放按钮  //display the zoom button
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);//开启多点触控  //turn on the multiple touch feature
    mapView.getController().setZoom(13);


    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
    mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(39.9,116.3));//设置中心点 //set the center 
    //定位当前位置 // locate to current position
    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
```

Comment: You should translate your comment in to english language.

Comment: Also, if you could add a bried statement about how your code addresses the problem, that would be good. The top line of your code is outside the code block also.

Answer (score 0):

I think from looking at other samples, that you miss permissions.
unless the map is already cached on your device, you definitely need to access INTERNET. 
try this set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Note that if you are targeting Android devices >= 6.0 (SDK >= 23), you have to check for "dangerous" permissions at runtime. Dangerous permissions needed by osmdroid are: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION/ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Refer to this [implementation](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/MainActivity.java)

take from: "How to use the osmdroid library" - [link](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated the OSM map in my application. 
Following class is used 
1.OSMMap activity 
2.OSMMap ItemizedOverlay
Three jar has to copy into lib folder of Project->App->lib 
OSMBonusPack-v5.8.1-sources(1).jar
osmdroid-android-4.3.jar
slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar
1.OSMmap Activity

```
 public class OSMMap extends Activity
    {
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mapController;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    String date,time,vname;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_osmmap2);

        //Coming Parameter is from vehicleinfo activity
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(bundle.getString("lat"));
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+latitude);
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(bundle.getString("lng"));
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+longitude);
        date = bundle.getString("date");
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+date);
        time = bundle.getString("time");
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+time);
        vname = bundle.getString("vname");
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+vname);
        mapView= (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
//        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.BASE_OVERLAY_NL);

//        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.CYCLEMAP);
//        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
//      mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.BASE);
//        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
//      mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTAERIAL);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapController= (MapController) mapView.getController();
        Log.i("CPA","In the map view"+mapView);

//      GeoPoint geoPoint=new GeoPoint(40.712784,-74.005941);
        GeoPoint geoPoint=new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+latitude);
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+longitude);
        mapController.setZoom(8);
        mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSM map method"+geoPoint);
        Log.i("CPA","In the OSsM map method");

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_marker);

        OSMDemo itemizedoverlay = new OSMDemo(drawable,this);
        itemizedoverlay.setEnabled(true);

        OverlayItem overlayItem=new OverlayItem("Vehicle"+time,"VEHICLE NO"+date,geoPoint);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(18);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(geoPoint);

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    }

}
```

2.OSM ItemizedOverlay

```
public class OSMDemo extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{

    static ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public OSMDemo(Drawable pDefaultMarker, Context context)
    {

        super(pDefaultMarker,new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(context));
        mContext=context;

    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();

    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
    {
        return mOverlays.get(0);

    }
    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int i, int i1, Point point, IMapView iMapView)
    {


        return false;
    }

    public boolean ontap(int index)
    {

        Log.i("CPA","In the OSMDEMO ONTAP");
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;

    }
}
```