# Route-Me for android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to load a number of tiled layer and animates them. In `iPhone` we have mapping package called `Route-Me`. Is there is any mapping package for android like `Route-Me`? Do you know if the built-in mapping package for android easily supports external tiled layers?

Comment: Have you got solution for your question..??

Comment: The answer is yes, see my answer & link below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Google Maps API supports Overlays but, unlilke Route-me or iOS4, you have to do all the heavy lifting yourself in the onDraw() method.

Comment: Could you give an example, we're talking custom tiles. Which btw isn't allowed based on the documentation afaik.

Comment: I don't see where the documentation doesn't allow it. In fact AndNav does it : http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/TilesOverlay.java

Comment: Your linking to osmdroid, they have their own map implementation... here is another link to a similar post with a reply from commonsware (who knows a fair deal about android)

Comment: Please look at my link before shooting it down : it's an overlay implementation that does exactly what the OP wants. He can adapt it to his need and its proves it can be done.

Comment: Yes but it is not android mapview. It is a custom view called osmdroid. Just trying to point out that youre wrong when you say google maps api supports this feature.

Comment: Go read about osmdroid. It also uses openstreetview maps data. Its completly decoupled from google mapview.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're talking about. The issue here is  Overlays (no matter what map background). This is what the OP wants. The code I link to handles overlay image positionning, downloading & caching. Did you notice that someone else left a link to the same project on your answer...

Comment: And by the way, I've actually written an app that does that so I am right when I say google maps api supports it.

Comment: But you are not just overriding the onDraw of the google mapview. You are using osmdroid. Which isn't google but someone else. That was my point, nothing else. You are right in everything else.

Comment: Oh, that's your argument ! There isn't a "TiledPngOverlay" class provided by google. Ok, but that's not what the OP is asking... he's asking if it "easily supports it". I wouldn't say it's easy if you write it yourself but there is code out that does make it easy.

Comment: I never argued you were wrong about osmdroid, or that you weren't right it was possible, I only stated you wasn't correct with google maps, as it isn't google maps but osmdroid. If microsoft made a maps implementation for android called bing.maps you wouldn't go around calling it google maps now would you?

Comment: Seriously... you're coming back for more ? Stop, you're making a fool of yourself : it is possible to do a tiled-PNG overlay using google's APIs. Period.

Comment: Sorry for going into detail with words. The OP just need to use osmdroid and he's good :) you can call the api whatever you feel like and your good.

Comment: Quoting from your own comment "Which btw isn't allowed based on the documentation afaik". That's not "going into detail with words", that's just something I proved wrong. Can you not simply accept having made an honest mistake and that you learned something. That's the whole point of this site you know... learning & sharing.

Comment: I didn't learn anything, you didn't learn anything, but I don't care, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Android maps doesn't support this feature. You should look into osmdroid or one of the other open source maps implementations.

Edit: To provide extra detail:

The osmdroid project can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Here is a question on stack with some implementation but still struggling with some detail: [OSMDroid simple example required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327399/osmdroid-simple-example-required).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170265/osmdroid-how-i-can-create-and-load-a-map-from-my-own-bitmapstiles) is another similar stack question with additional detail.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithTilesOverlayAndCustomTileSource.java?r=860) is the osmdroid example with custom tile source.