# Overlays in osmdroid-android-3.0.3.jar

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'd previously managed to incorporate OpenStreetMaps into my application using osmdroid-android-3.0.1.jar with the great assistance of the answer to my question

[Porting a Google Maps app to Osmdroid - problem with overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910410/porting-a-google-maps-app-to-osmdroid-problem-with-overlay)

I've now upgraded to using the 3.0.3 jar and can't get my overlay to display.

My app can switch display from Google Maps to OSM and display the same overlay consisting of lines and texts on top of either. The alternative displays each run in their own activity for now, as the classes are similar but do not have absolutely identical methods, or at least they didn't have in 3.0.1. (Ultimately I'd like to use the Osmdroid wrapper jar to combine them in one activity and reduce the duplicate code, but that's a question for a later date) Right now I'd like to get the same functionality as I had with the now deprecated 3.0.1 jar using the new 3.0.3 version.

With the new jar, I still get the mapview displayed OK but the overlay has disappeared. I've had to make some changes to the code, as the 3.0.1 onDraw() method has now been replaced with draw() (just like Google) in the **MapOverlay extends org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay** class.

All the code in the previous onDraw() (now draw) method has been copied verbatim from the answer to the question referred to above, It worked fine, although I confess to not fully understanding the concepts of worldsize, bounding boxes and the transformation described.

I notice that the method

```
final Point upperLeft = org.osmdroid.views.util.Mercator
            .projectGeoPoint(boundingBox.getLatNorthE6(), boundingBox.getLonWestE6(),
            zoomLevel + tileZoom, null);
```

is now deprecated, and I had to remove tileZoom and

```
final int tileZoom = projection.getTileMapZoom();
```

to get it to compile.

When I get to the code in the draw() method, I can see in the debugger that all the data necessary to draw the overlay is still present and correct. The drawing is done by lines such as canvas.drawLine(....) and canvas.drawText(....). I've not used the extra parameter to the function (boolean shadow) at all.

My redrawOverlay() method remains as:

```
private void redrawOverlay() {

    mGpt = mMapVw.getMapCenter();

    if (mmapOverlay == null)
        mmapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this);
    mmapOverlay.setEnabled(true);
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mMapVw.getOverlays();
    int ovlSize = listOfOverlays.size();
    if (ovlSize > 1)
        listOfOverlays.remove(1);
    listOfOverlays.add(mmapOverlay);
    mMapVw.invalidate();
}
```

(The Google listofOverlays.clear() shouldn't be used as osmdroid 3.0.1 had element 0 as the map itself - hence the remove(1))

I'm wondering what I have to do to modify the existing 3.0.1 code to work with 3.0.3? I'm hoping that one of the authors of might read this question.

**Update**

By adapting the Minimap overaly as suggested in the answer to the question referred to above, the draw() method for drawing an overlay from top left to bottom right, now becomes:

```
    @Override
    protected void draw(Canvas pC,  MapView pOsmv, boolean shadow) {
        if(shadow)
            return;

        Paint lp3;
        lp3 = new Paint();
        lp3.setColor(Color.RED);
        lp3.setAntiAlias(true);
        lp3.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        lp3.setStrokeWidth(1);
        lp3.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        lp3.setTextSize(12);
        // Calculate the half-world size
          final Rect viewportRect = new Rect();
          final Projection projection = pOsmv.getProjection();
          final int zoomLevel = projection.getZoomLevel();
          int mWorldSize_2 = TileSystem.MapSize(zoomLevel) / 2;

          // Save the Mercator coordinates of what is on the screen
          viewportRect.set(projection.getScreenRect());
          // DON'T set offset with either of below
          //viewportRect.offset(-mWorldSize_2, -mWorldSize_2);
          //viewportRect.offset(mWorldSize_2, mWorldSize_2);

          // Draw a line from one corner to the other
          pC.drawLine(viewportRect.left, viewportRect.top, viewportRect.right, viewportRect.bottom, lp3);
    }
```

This works OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to suggest a few things:

1. In the new jar build, calling getOverlays().clear() will no longer remove the map tile overlay. Calling remove(1) may be incorrect now since the map tile overlay is no longer in position 0.
2. The projection has a method that will get you the screen coordinate rectangle of what is currently on the screen. You can check the coordinates you use to draw your lines with against this rectangle to make sure they intercept it.
3. Take a look at the new TileSystem class. Anything that was deprecated can be recreated using these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I managed to get it working by adapting the Minimap overlay as you had suggested before. I noticed that the setting of the offset has to be removed in order for it work, this isn't like the Minimap example though (see update). I also noted that my on TouchEvent, which I was using to implement the 'doubleTap' by timing the time between two ACTION_DOWN events, appears to be triggered twice within 1ms on a single touch?

Comment: The reason you don't need to offset, is that the getScreenRect() gets the ready-to-draw screen coordinates of what's on the screen. In other words, it's pre-offset.

You should be able to override onDoubleTap (or something like that) in your overlay to get a double tap event.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The app is looking quite good now. I particularly like the seamless integration of the zipped tiles into the tile source. Is there any property I can set on the TileSource such that it will only get the tiles from the zip or the cache and not go online?

Comment: Absolutely - you need to build your own tile provider chain. Take a look at the MapTileProviderArray. You can pass it an array of tile provider "modules" (in the modules namespace). If you look at the MapTileProviderBasic, it will show how to create a tile provider chain.

Comment: Thank you once again. I've had a brief look and it seems like an interesting exercise for me next week.